# install python2.7.3 + numpy + scipy + matplotlib + scikits.statsmodels + pandas0.7.3 correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib

...using Linux (xubuntu).
How to install python2.7.3 + numpy + scipy + matplotlib + scikits.statsmodels + pandas0.7.3 correctly ? My final aim is to have them working. The problem:

```
~$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

so i already have a system-default 2.7.3, which is good!

```
~$ dpkg -s python-numpy
Package: python-numpy
Status: install ok installed
```

and i already have numpy installed! great! But...

```
~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Oct 23 2012, 01:07:38) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as nmp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

this module couldn't be find by python. The same with scipy, matplotlib. Why?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
[...] 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version.
[...]
```

why it does not see numpy and others ?

update:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>>>
```

so i do have /usr/local/lib/python2.7

```
~$ pip freeze
Warning: cannot find svn location for distribute==0.6.16dev-r0
BzrTools==2.4.0
CDApplet==1.0
[...]
matplotlib==1.0.1
mutagen==1.19
numpy==1.5.1
[...]
pandas==0.7.3
papyon==0.5.5
[...]
pytz==2012g
pyxdg==0.19
reportlab==2.5
scikits.statsmodels==0.3.1
scipy==0.11.0
[...]
zope.interface==3.6.1
```

as you can see, those modules are already installed! But! ls -la /usr/local/lib/ gives ONLY python2.7 dir. And still

```
~$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

and

> > > import sys
> > >       sys.version
> > >           '2.7.3 (default, Oct 23 2012, 01:07:38) \n[GCC 4.6.1]'

updated:

Probably I've missed another instance... One at `/usr/Python-2.7.3/` and second (seems to be installed "by hands" far far ago) at `/usr/python2.7.3/Python-2.7.3/`
 But how two identical versions can work at the same time??? Probably, one of them is "disabled" (not used by any program, but I don't know how to check if any program uses it).

```
~$ ls -la /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 2011-11-01 11:11 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2476800 2012-09-28 19:48 /usr/bin/python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1452 2012-09-28 19:45 /usr/bin/python2.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2586060 2012-07-21 01:42 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1652 2012-07-21 01:40 /usr/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 2011-10-05 23:53 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 2011-09-06 02:04 /usr/bin/python3.2 -> python3.2mu
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2852896 2011-09-06 02:04 /usr/bin/python3.2mu
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 2011-10-08 19:50 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

there is a symlink python->python2.7, maybe I can `ln -f -s`  this link to exact /usr/Python-2.7.3/python destination without harm ?? And how correctly to remove the 'copy' of 2.7.3?
And else...

```
~$ ls -la /usr/bin/virtualenv 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 58 2011-03-16 18:55 /usr/bin/virtualenv
```

but works only in this case:

```
~$ /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/virtualenv qenv
New python executable in qenv/bin/python
Installing distribute....................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
```

and this doesn't work!

```
 python virtualenv.py pyenv
```

I will try to be more clear. Just questions. Why I can import numpy starting '/usr/bin/python' but can not by using only 'python'? If I want to install another version of python for different applications, what is the best way to do this? How to install packages into chosen pythonpath? I did not find a complete guide.

---

Thanks to everyone!
Solved it this way:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/python/debian_defaults
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.Y_old
$ sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

My default version was 2.7.3 and now it's 2.7.2+. I do not see huge difference, so I think it was quite safe. But I need to read more about

> virtualenv

and

> pip
>   and default 
>   PATH

Comment: Have you actually tried running `/usr/bin/python` and then tried the imports? I don't see any indication of that. As for removing those other version, I can you can disable them by e.g. `sudo mv /usr/Python-2.7.3 /usr/Python-2.7.3-disabled`. If everything then keeps working, `sudo rm -r /usr/Python-2.7.3-disabled` will really get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, running /usr/bin/python worked perfectly! Successfully imported numpy. BUT! I still do not understand the way how to manage only one python version, how to use exactly the version i need to run for a program.

Comment: either remove the other Python installation (or better, move them aside), or make sure that in your `PATH`, `/usr/bin` comes *before* `/usr/local/bin` and other (bin) directories that contain Python. Your shell picks the first `python` executable it can find on your `PATH`. If you don't really know how to do that, you may be better off making that a new question (including listing the contents of your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and a few other `.bash*` files that you can find. Assuming your using `bash`, which is the default shell on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recomend you to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/). Virtualenv allows you to create python environment in per project basis. My workflow to begin a new project is

- Create the project directory `myapp`
- Download virtualenv from https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/develop
- Create a virtual environment: `python virtualenv.py pyenv`
- Activate the virtualenv `source pyenv/bin/activate`
- Install the packages in the virtual environment:

  `pip install -U numpy matplotlib pandas ...`

With this setup, you can control the version, reinstall or remove the packages without have to depend on the version that is available in the repositories.

Comment: I've done all steps with only one exception - it didn't see virtualenv.py, so I used a full path. Next installed all needed packages, but still get the same error. I don't understand. making 'pip freeze' shows everything I need already installed.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better asked in a Xubuntu forum, because it is most probably a configuration issue. Is there perhaps more than one version of python installed?

In the python interpreter, type the following code;

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Verify that the numpy directory is installed in one of the directories listed in `sys.path`.

On my FreeBSD (UNIX-like) system with python 2.7.3, numpy is installed as a subdirectory of `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. On windows it is probably `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\`.

If you e.g. also have a python 3.x installed, it could be that numpy et cetera in installed for that python. In that case, look in `/usr/local/lib/python3.x/site-packages/` or `C:\Python3x\Lib\site-packages\`.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a custom-installed Python 2.7.3 in `/usr/local/bin`. Using `/usr/bin/python`, you should be able to `import numpy`; `apt-get` installs to `/usr` but never `/usr/local`.

Comment: Thank you for response. I've added an update to my post.

Comment: @boldnik: there's no such thing as a "disabled" Python installation. Type `which python` to find out which one you're running and change your `PATH` appropriately if it's not the one you want.